# My battery cycle count surpassed 1000 (MacBook Pro Retina Late 2012)

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

It already passed 1000 cycle counts, and it doesn't say to replace yet. When I check the condition it states "Normal."

I already order a new battery, because I was under the impression after I reach the limit of cycles count I would need to replace the battery. I restarted my Mac to see if it changes the conditions, but it did not. It still shows "Normal".

Should I replace the battery anyways with the new or wait until it says "Condition: Replace"

Comment: You could install Battery Health from http://www.fiplab.com/.   It makes these sorts of things clear.  Count yourself lucky that your battery has held up so well.

Comment: Lucky you! I have the same model / year and 907 cycles. My battery is so bad: macbook turns off when it does some "heavy" computing and the battery is ~30% loaded. The fully loaded battery lasts ~2 hours on medium work load. Don´t replace it until the battery is like mine.. ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Lithium batteries lose capacity over time, as you recharge them. Your MacBook can sustain 1000 recharge cycles and still retain 80% of its original capacity (more or less).

What this means is that if your battery originally held 10000 mAh, then in its current state of wear and tear it now holds 8000 mAh (80% of original). When you charge it up to 100%, you're now only charging it to 8000 mAh. Your battery has shrunk by 20%, so to speak.

What this means is your battery drains a little faster than before. But unless the lowered capacity truly bothers you, you've still got some time to go before you need to replace it. If you were okay with it at 81% of original capacity, I doubt you’ll notice a difference at 79% or 75% of original capacity.

Replace your battery when your laptop can no longer operate long enough to accommodate your needs without having to plug in, or when **System Information** advises you to replace it. If you always use your MacBook while plugged in, you likely won't need to replace its battery before you want to buy a new laptop entirely.

1000 cycles isn't a "limit," only a reference. You can go through many more cycles than that.

Comment: So far I have not noticed the capacity lowering. Even though my cycle count has surpass it's limit, it's still charging up to 100 percent.

Comment: Yes, it's 100% of a lower capacity, compared to a brand-new battery. When your battery is at 100%, it only holds about 80% of the power it used to hold when it was brand-new.

Comment: 1000 charge cycles isn't a "limit." It's a reference value, at which point your battery only holds 80% of its initial capacity.

Answer (score 11):

No worries, my late 2009 MacBook has just surpassed 2000 battery cycles and still has 75% health. :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).